# Hibernate cannot open connection in server

Tags: hibernate

Hi am developing an struts+hibernate website. I have an issue with the hibernate connection problem. When i am using it in my localhost it is working properly. The issue is i am using the same configuration file with the server database connection username and password the connection not open. I have write the error message to a file in server and it shows the error message as "**Cannot open connection**".

Here is my hibernate configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<?xmsl version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory name="session1">
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev_mydatabase?autoReconnect=false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myusername(not original)</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypassword(no original)</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">managed</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>

    <!-- For seeing hibernate log on the console -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <!-- End-->

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL">trace</property>
    <!--    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->

<!-- All my mapping files are here.-->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and in my dao file i write query as

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory =
                    (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);
            Session Hibernatesession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Hibernatesession.beginTransaction();
            doctorList = Hibernatesession.createCriteria("Hibernate query will be here").
```

I don't understand what is the issue occured here. Any one please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the **localhost** in your hibernate config as shown below. Change it to point to the actual db address and port.

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev_mydatabase?autoReconnect=false</property>
```

Comment: No the connection details i provide here is dummy data. The actual data in my hibernate config file is different. I have tested the connection with a simple jsp page. it worked perfectly.

Comment: @anoopkattodi post the stacktrace then

Comment: actually i don't know how to take stracktrace from server. I have uses log4j for getting the log from the server. It only says **could no open connection**..

Comment: Guys it is worked. The problem was not really in the configuration file. I have used different different database name in my server so i need to change it in my hbm files. Once it change and restart tomcat it worked. Anyway thank you Panega